# Imported Meshes in a FBX comes in wrong Postion and Rotation

Tags: import

I bought this model from Unity Asset Store and imported it to blender. And here's what I get in Blender:

[image]

It should be a Motorbike like this:

[image]

Here's the FBX:

https://mega.nz/file/7UVDxKKK#xMAjJvdxEVZcIgE0oTZKnz5HeyT4NoZGu7CsNS53o04

Comment: It looks the same for me, but it looks right in the Windows 3d viewer. After I Save As glb with it and import it to Blender the positions will be fixed. Try to convert the file or export from Unity.

Comment: yeah I figured the issue myself· too. We 've got to convert the file by whatever means